# MYSQL Multiple Composite Index with ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some doubts about MYSQL multiple composite indexes with ranges. 
For example, if i have the following index:

`Multiple column index in columns (A, B, C)`

And the following query

`WHERE A=2 AND B>5 AND C=3`

Question:
 - The index will use the columns (A,B,C) or only (A, B)

And what about this one:

`WHERE A=2 AND B IN (1,2,3) AND C=4`

Thanks!

Comment: No index will be used.  The syntax is invalid, so you will get an error.

Comment: its pseudocode, come on...

Comment: Does MySQL have a query execution plan, like SQL Server?

Comment: @WEI_DBA The `EXPLAIN` statement will show the query execution plan.

Comment: @WEI_DBA But it will just tell you which indexes are used, not which columns in a multi-column index are used.

Comment: I think it should be able to satisfy these conditions entirely from the index, but I don't know how to prove that it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: - The index will use the columns (A,B,C) or only (A, B)

Most likely (A, B). Indexes are positional, so they can't access the next column if the previous one is not using equality. But depending on table stats a full table scan may be faster.

> WHERE A=2 AND B IN (1,2,3) AND C=4

Maybe:

- only (A), or
- (A, B) three times,
- or none of them by doing a full table scan.

Statistics will decidedly make a big difference. In essence, is `A` very selective or not? If not, then a full table scan may be faster than using the index.